# Gallop correctly with freestyle in swimming?

Tags: swimming, freestyle

I know that there are many Olympian swimmers that gallop in freestyle. Take Jason Lezak, Michael Phelps, even Katie Ledecky! However, how do I gallop in swimming so that I don’t get myself and my muscles unbalanced and crooked? Is it a bad idea to gallop at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I gallop in swimming so that I don’t get myself and my muscles unbalanced and crooked?

Simple: Your muscles will grow from training, not from your races - and you won't be doing this in all your races anyway, if at all.

During training don't do the gallop the whole time. It's a sprinting exercise only. If you're really concerned about being as balanced as possible, then alternate the sides that you do the gallop in during training: one day breath to the left, other day to the right - but, of course, use only your preferred side during a race.

> Is it a bad idea to gallop at all?

You may not end up using it during your races, but it's surely worth experimenting with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will adjust my swimming accordingly :)